# how to serialize object into json using c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, json.net

I tried using

```
var myobject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Customer);
```

but problem is in `Customer` properties are like

`FirstName` and my service expecting json input like `firstName`
`{"firstName":"Neo"}`

statement `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Customer);` gives me `{"FirstName":"Neo"}` which is wrong.

> So How can I change first letter when JsonConvert.SerializeObject happened ?

Or How to take only one parameter as input json `firstname` instead if using Customer object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define how data need to be serialized.
When using webapi, we can define a CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver (part of json.net library) as formatter in the register method of the webapi config.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    { 
       config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();            
    }
}
```

The code above is especially for webapi, nevertheless I believe a simular approach can be a solution when not using webapi.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [Json.NET attribute support](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm) to customize the naming:

```
public class Customer
{
    [JsonProperty("firstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this. Use `DataMember` property, it'll serailize as mentioned.

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class Customer 
{
    [DataMember(Name = "firstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```